# generate hashed password on findOneAndUpdate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

my pre findOneAndUpdate in my schema doesn't work

here is my currently pre findOneAndUpdate that doesn't work(it does nothing)

```
userSchema.pre('findOneAndUpdate', function (next) {
    this.update({}, { $set: { location: 'hey' } });
}
```

"this" parameter is the query like explained [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#notes)

> Query middleware differs from document middleware in a subtle but
>   important way: in document middleware, this refers to the document
>   being updated. In query middleware, mongoose doesn't necessarily have
>   a reference to the document being updated, so this refers to the query
>   object rather than the document being updated.

here is my update function that I copied from [this](https://github.com/volodymyrrudyi/generic-express-mongoose-controller-example/blob/master/resources/controllers/base.js) project:

```
async update(id, data) {
        var filter = {};
        filter[this.key] = id;
        let updatedModel = await this.model.findOneAndUpdate(filter, data, { new: true });

        if (!updatedModel) {
            throw new Error(`update - not found ${id} for ${this.modelName}`);
        }
    }
```

and here is my schema:

```
let userSchema = new Schema({
    first_name: { type: String },
    last_name: { type: String },
    username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    admin: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    location: String,
    created_at: { type: Date, default: Date.now() },
    last_login_at: { type: Date, default: Date.now() },
    resetPasswordToken: String,
    resetPasswordExpires: Date
});
```

the only solution I found to hash the password on an update is to hash the password before calling the update method is it currently the accepted solution?
or is there any workaround that I could hash the password on pre findOneAndUpdate

Comment: Keep reading down the [documentation page](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#notes) - *"Pre and post save() hooks are **not executed** on update(), findOneAndUpdate(), etc. You can see a more detailed discussion why in this GitHub issue. Mongoose 4.0 introduced distinct hooks for these functions."* So there is a "different hook" now for this instead of `save`.

Comment: I know that pre save doesn't execute on findOneAndUpdate, I just put that code there to show that pre save is working and only the pre findOneAndUpdate doesn't I will delete the pre save code to not confuse people. I looked in the duplicate and it really has my answer, just need to change this._update.$set.admin to this._update.admin. thank you!